# Sorting firstname alphabetically

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, logic, alphabetical

I have one issue about code solving challenge... as the last requirement it says that if score of two people are equal, then sort them alphabetically, for instance:

in case: Matthew and Elizabeth, the first comes Matthew
in case: Chloe and Abigail, the first comes Abigail
in case: Isabella Natalie, the first comes Isabella

Who can explain the logic of sorting them?
If we say just comparing letters, the first case should be Elizabeth, not Matthew

Comment: With the information that you've given us, the assignment is clearly wrong, since Matthew coming before Elizabeth is not alphabetical sorting. But I feel that there is important information that is missing from your question. Such as the scores of the two people.

Comment: Is there a last name also? Sorting by name usually means sorting by last name, then first name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full problem so I can't say for sure, but you said that "if the score of two people are equal, then sort alphabetically." Most likely then, Elizabeth has a lower score than Matthew. If Elizabeth and Matthew had the same score then Elizabeth would appear first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a Map by sorting by value and then key, assuming the score is the value and name is the key.

check this out [implementation of above suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709769/how-to-sort-map-entries-by-values-first-then-by-key-and-put-the-ordered-keys-in)